# Impersonate user for specific client

Tags: keycloak

I deploy a Keycloak-Instance. A requirement is for the Helpdesk to be able to impersonate users.

There is a impersonation-button in the Admin-GUI, great. But the Impersonation-Button gets me access_token for the account-console. I need token for other Clients. Is there a way of "Log into App X as User Y with Using my Admin-Permissions"?

The Impersonation-Endpoint seems not to provide a feature to specify the app to impersonate (https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_impersonate).

EDIT: I'm sorry, it was caused by a bug on my side! Make sure that you aren't logged in in any other app in the realm and that you also don't trigger the logout-function of any app after pressing Impersonate! (or otherwise you have to redo everything)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear (at least to me) what exactly is your requirement. What does impersonate mean in your requirements? And are you trying to impersonate an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impersonation in keycloak is `realm` level. The `access_token` that you got from impersonate button is not limited to `account-console`, it can be used by other clients(or applications) from same realm. Try accessing any other application/client from same realm. You should be able to directly access that application.

If you want to limit impersonation to specific client then you have to extend the Authenticator and implement logic yourself.